# Windivert filter error: IfIdx

Tags: c++, windows, networking, filter, interface

I am trying to use the following filter to divert packages but it fails:

```
WinDivertOpen("IfIdx == X", WINDIVERT_LAYER::WINDIVERT_LAYER_NETWORK, 0, 0);
```

I am tasting a program which has to divert traffic from a specific interface whose index is X (0, 1, 2, ...) but I get an error code number 87, this indicates an invalid packet filter string, layer, priority, or flags.

If I try to use other filter like "tcp" It works, but I only need to apply the filter to an specific interface whose index I already know. If this filter key does not work.. What solutions am I able to do?.

Here is the documentation: https://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#filter_language

Regards and thank you.

Edit: I also tried this:

```
handle = WinDivertOpen("true", WINDIVERT_LAYER::WINDIVERT_LAYER_NETWORK, 0, 0);

if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    printf("ERROR WINDIVERT: %d", GetLastError());

else
{
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (WinDivertRecv(handle, packet, sizeof(packet), &addr, &packetLen))
        {
            if (addr.IfIdx != X)
            {
                WinDivertSend(handle, packet, packetLen, &addr, NULL);
            }
        }
    }

    WinDivertClose(handle);
```

But It blocked the traffic of all interfaces and did not only block the traffic of my specific interface whose index is X.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using `IfIdx` when the correct token is `ifIdx` (lowercase `i`).  Btw, if you upgrade to WinDivert1.2 you can use the `WinDivertHelperCheckFilter` function to get a more helpful error message.

As for your edit; could be a number of problems such as not recalculating checksums (if necessary) before `WinDivertSend`.  See the `passthru.c` sample program.